# Display the sum of records in the view - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sum

I have a scope that should return the sum of a column (model and scope underneath)

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :membership
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :membership

 attr_accessible :membership_attributes, :forename, :middlename, :surname, :house_no, :house_name, :street, :town, :postcode, :home_tel, :mobile_tel, :work_tel, :email, :start_date, :expiry_date

scope :new_memberships_cash_today, ->() {
joins(:membership).where(:start_date => Date.today).sum('memberships.cost')}
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :members, :dependent => :destroy
 attr_accessible :membership_type, :cost 
end
```

When i run the scope in the console i get this returned

```
<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Member id: 26, forename: "Richard", middlename: "C", surname: "Lewis", house_no: 10, house_name: "", street: "testRoad", town: "test town", postcode: "cf5 6gh7GA", home_tel: "01633 222222", mobile_tel: "07855666995", work_tel: "02920 111111", email: "richlewis14@test.com", created_at: "2013-12-11 16:46:44", updated_at: "2013-12-17 10:12:26", membership_id: 3, start_date: "2013-12-17", expiry_date: "2014-01-16">]>
```

So the scope has matched on the start_date and I have a membership_id, from which i should be able to access the attribute cost from membership?.. I cant seem to access it though in my view

In the view i am trying to display that sum

```
columns do

  #Todays Memberships
   column do
    panel "Todays Memberships", :class => 'todayscashmemberships' do
     table_for Member.new_memberships_cash_today do 
       column("Amount")  do |m| 
         "#{m.membership.cost}"
       end


     end
    end
   end
  end
```

The error i get is

```
undefined method `to_key' for 71.95999908447266:Float
```

Could anyone point out what i am doing wrong and maybe explain for future reference

Thanks

Comment: where are you calling 'to_key'? does the count work in console?

Comment: when i try to render the view, this is when i get the error

Comment: also, how would i run the count in the console? how would i retrieve the value of cost?

Comment: i think problem in this scope `new_memberships_cash_today` return   '71.95999908447266:Float' and you try iterate on activeadmin and call `membership.cost` on float

Comment: how do i get the value outputted @Monk_Code ? I don't need to iterate? just show the value?

Comment: so would it just be membership.cost ? no iteration

Comment: just panel or something

Comment: so that i understand what you mean would you mind showing me an example as an answer, ill happily mark as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think problem in this scope 
  `new_memberships_cash_today` return `71.95999908447266:Float` and you try iterate on table_for and call `membership.cost` on float.

Try without iterations just panel or something.

I do not remember `ActiveAdmin DSL` one way or try to read the documentation

```
columns do
  column do
     span Member.new_memberships_cash_today.to_s
  end
end
```

Comment: that's great but i don't know how the column structure would look without a block or as a panel like you specify